# What is this tan-coloured cup-shaped mushroom found in northwestern UK?

Tags: identification, fungus, mushrooms, concrete

I found this tan-coloured cup-shaped mushroom growing in my back garden on the concrete behind the bin. I'm in the northwestern UK and it's been very wet here recently.

[image]

What is this mushroom? Is it dangerous?

Comment: Some sort of Fungus - common, I don't recall the name. Should be fine if you are not planning to eat it. Might or might not be fine if you are. Or might be a slime mold, which are evidently no longer considered to be fun guys.

Comment: With [tag:identification] questions, it's useful to describe where in the world you found the plant, and the conditions where you found it (sun, shade, rocky hillside, forested riverbank, and so on). If you have more information about the plant, please update your question to add it. Thanks.

Comment: See here for more details.http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/20274/what-fungus-is-this/20276. Related, not exactly the same. Harmless.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, not slime mold. Something from the pezizales family. Harmles unless eaten. (Some are even edible.)

Comment: Hi sorry I'm brand new to this. I'm from north west uk. It's been very wet here recently and this is growing behind my bin on the concrete. I couldn't find anything about it in the Internet so just curious if it's mould or plant or ?

Comment: Its just a cup fungus, nothing to worry about. If you don't like the look of them, break them off, but the mycelium or root system will be present in the soil beneath - these are just the fruiting bodies. With all the rain we're having, and the mild weather, I'm not surprised mushrooms are still popping up everywhere - along with daffodils being in flower in the south. It is, indeed, one of the peziza fungi

Comment: @RyanWhite - wasn't sure whether I should have pinged you in my comment above for you to see it, so I'm doing that now...